# React performance problem: Suppress recalculation of all components when modal opens (<body> overflow change)

Tags: reactjs, performance, modal-dialog

According to this article https://itnext.io/what-to-do-when-your-react-app-feels-slow-3744c966ddf every visible react component gets recalculated when react-bootstrap modal opens, because of overflow change on body element.

I have a table and want to edit some rows in a modal. If there are more than 300 rows it is noticeable that the modal opening time takes much longer.

The modal lives in a separate component and is created with ReactDom.createPortal and i have no render call on my other components, so i conclude this performance drop comes from dom recalculation.

Is there any workaround, so not every component will be recalculated or is it just bad design to use a modal in such case?

Comment: maybe virtual list?

Comment: Tried it with a virtual list, which gives me indeed a performance boost. So i get the feeling there is no other way to optimize modal load without limiting loaded elements. Thank you for the hint.